# No valid EE environment for injection of org.infinispan.cdi.event.cachemanager.CacheManagerEventBridge

Tags: infinispan

I am trying to deploy the Cdi-quickstart application on Glassfish 3.1.1. I am getting the following error in the server.log file
'code'

```
SEVERE: No valid EE environment for injection of org.infinispan.cdi.event.cachemanager.CacheManagerEventBridge
SEVERE: No valid EE environment for injection of org.infinispan.cdi.DefaultCacheConfigurationProducer
SEVERE: No valid EE environment for injection of org.infinispan.quickstart.cdi.config.Config
SEVERE: No valid EE environment for injection of org.infinispan.quickstart.cdi.config.Config
```

I am not able to figure out how to solve this error.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem.....

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Got the same issue in a different context, also Glassfish 3.1.(1|2). There is no stacktrace. Just the warning.